# How do I use PostSharp to do call stack aggregated logging?

Tags: logging, profiling, aggregate, aop, postsharp

I'm currently using PostSharp to do AOP performance logging, and I'd like to do some aggregated variants on ProfilerAspects.

One variant I'm interested in is aggregating the logging by the first function called with that aspect. Hopefully this example should make it clear: I'd like to have an aspect called EntryAggregatedProfiler, and two methods A and B as below:

```
[EntryAggregatedProfiler] 
public int A(int depth) 
{ 
  Thread.sleep(100); // sleep 100 milliseconds
  if (depth > 0) return depth; 
  return A(depth + 1); 
}

[EntryAggregatedProfiler] 
public int B() 
{ 
  Thread.sleep(50); 
  return A(0); 
}
```

I would like my profiler aspect to create one entry when A(0) is called. The log entry for A(0) should be of the following form:

```
<function name="A"> 
    <args> 
        <depth type="int">0</depth> 
    </args> 
    <function name="A"> 
        <args> 
            <depth type="int">1</depth> 
        </args> 
        <callTime>105</callTime> 
    </function> 
    <callTime>210</callTime> 
</function>
```

And a call to B() should create one log entry like

```
<function name="B"> 
    <args /> 
    <function name="A"> 
        <args> 
            <depth type="int">0</depth> 
        </args> 
        <function name="A"> 
            <args> 
                <depth type="int">1</depth> 
            </args> 
            <callTime>105</callTime> 
        </function> 
        <callTime>210</callTime> 
    </function> 
    <callTime>265</callTime> 
</function>
```

Secondly, I'd also like to have this created on the class level, so the same design pattern as above, but with both A and B as methods within a class:

```
[ClassEntryAggregatedLogger] 
public class C 
{ 
   public int A(int depth) 
  { 
.......etc...... 
}
```

So a call to C.A(0) and C.B() should produce similar results to above.

Answer (score 0):

You can take inspiration from examples at http://samples.postsharp.net/.

There is one example about logging which also includes indentation reflecting the call stack. There is also another example about profiling.

The aspect (logging or profiling) extending the `OnMethodBoundaryAspect` class can be applied to a particular method, class or multiple classes/methods at a time. So you don't need a special aspect to be applied to all methods of a class.